# Create the dynamic visio file in SharePoint 2013 On-premise

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, visio, visio-services

We have process item and the process have multiple steps to complete the process, we have keep steps items of each process into the `ProcessCapture` list.

I need to provide Export to Visio functionality feature to able to create a visio file along with Process related steps. Is there way to do with Jquery/Javascript api to create a dynamic visio file related to process item.

Here's helpful [link](https://bramdejager.wordpress.com/tag/visio-services/) to create a visio diagram into webpart using ECMAScript but unable to find out namespace of `VwaControl` namespace:

I really appreciate your suggestion on this.